# Heroku app crashing H10 error code in spite of restarting dynos

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra

I have a very basic Ruby/Sinatra app which I have pushed to Heroku successfully, however when I try and load the page it crashes.

Running heroku logs -t --app [app-name] produces the following error:

```
2016-03-02T11:43:31.024897+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=gothons-from-planet-percal.herokuapp.com request_id=6af6df55-d33d-4223-af5c-bd39fd788f1b fwd="46.252.71.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-03-02T11:43:31.773275+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=gothons-from-planet-percal.herokuapp.com request_id=401bcfb0-81da-4fb1-9b4e-e0877d0defcc fwd="46.252.71.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

I've tried running through the process to restart dynos, and it says it restarts the app but then the app crashes again. How can I fix this please?

Thank you.

Comment: what's in your procfile?

Comment: You can get a better detailed error log by running: `heroku run rails console`